# Show Image from Referenced Node

Tags: views, entities, panels

I am building a book review site. I have two kinds of content: 'Book Listing' and 'Review.' The Review content type has an entity reference field which links back to the Book Listing. Using entity prepopulate, I have created a button which opens the 'Review' add/edit form and automatically sets the value of the entity reference field to the corresponding Book Listing NID.

Now, what I would really like to do, since the button opens a new page, is add the book cover image that is on the Book Listing page to the add/edit form, to help the customer remember what they are reviewing. Amazon has a similar feature. To further complicate things, my 'Review' add/edit form is being rendered with panels. I've been playing around with views (with relationships) and passing arguments into the panel, but am not having any luck. Has anyone done something like this before? Any idea on what to try next?

Comment: Does the `'Review' add/edit form` url have the node id of the referenced entity (book listing)?

Answer (score 0):

With the relationship to the second content type properly defined (and possibly also required) you should be able to display the image requested.

One problem area I've seen is the base tables defined.  You can see the base table in the export text of a given view right on top.

If your base tables do in fact differ, then there are further nuances to the relational display in views, but it can be done.

Post back if you have more details to this view creation to guide a useful example.  I'll post more step by step instructions.